# Different instance inside a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Lately I have been trying to figure out a weird (for me) behaviour.

Let's say that I have a class with a *POD* attribute:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    vector<int> b; 
} Foo;

class Bar {
public:
    Foo foo;

    Bar(void);
    void increase(void);
};

Bar::Bar(void) {
    foo.a = 0;
}

void Bar::increase(void) {
    foo.a++;
    foo.b.push_back(foo.a);
}
```

There is no problem if I create a simple instance of *Bar* and work with it, but when I add it to a vector and access it throught an iterator, it access to a different memory location. For example:

```
Bar bar1, bar2; // foo.a = 0
bar1.increase(); // foo.a = 1
vector<Bar> data({bar1, bar2});
data.begin()->increase() // foo.a = garbage ??
```

When accessing to the iterator at begin I was expecting to access the *bar1* instance and the *a* field in the *foo* attribute with *1* as value, but it access a different memory location with garbage.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: This doesn't compile. The syntax for `Bar` inside `Bar` is not right. Is it supposed to be a constructor or a member variable or something else? You can't have a function named `do` (reserved keyword). You're missing `;` after your struct/class declarations.

Comment: There are a *lot* of problems with this code. 1) You don't have to say `struct` to name a type. 2) Your constructor is misspelled. 3) `do` is a keyword. 4) you're missing semicolons after class definitions. 5) Who exactly is POD?

Comment: Err... the code was just a snippet, a sample code, not strictly working code, to explain my question.... I fixed it :|

Comment: Works fine: [live example](http://ideone.com/Qt35KL).

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` makes its own copies of the objects when you call `push_back`

If you want to keep the same objects, try a vector of pointers (or smart pointers if you don't want to have to worry about tidying up the memory afterwards.)

Comment: That's not really the problem though.

Comment: I was expecting something like a copy, so I added a breakpoint to the constructor, but it wasn't executing twice for every instance.

Sorry for my ignorance about C++, but maybe it's using a *default copy* method, even if it isn't defined, so it doesn't need to call to the constructor again ?

Comment: @IñigoMartínez This is a red herring. Your code is fine. Maybe it is an issue with the debugger.